# Google sheets says "Finished script" but nothing happened

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 tabs – In Progress and Completed. I want to move the entire row if column A says "Completed". The script was run and there's a notification that says "Finished script" but nothing happened. Column 1 is a formula
but I want to paste them as values in "Completed" tab

```
    function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named In Progress
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // test column with Completed is col 1 or A
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "In Progress" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == "Completed") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
      }
    }
```

[image: GoogleSheetScreenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The script includes the condition

`s.getName() == "In Progress" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == "Completed"`

1. If any of those conditions aren't met, then the script will do nothing
2. onEdit is a reserved function name for a simple edit trigger and it's only triggered when the user makes a change, not when a formula is recalculated.